# Benefits / disadvantages to a cross origin domain proxy?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, jsonp

I'm struggling at the moment with the idea of creating a cross-origin request proxy or not.

I have a jQuery application that interacts with an API, making at least 4 requests to that server on the initial page load. Both servers are completely under my control, but they are on different subdomains. For that reason, I've been heading toward the approach of using JSONP to get around the cross-origin request policies.

However, I'm really missing out on one feature in particular: getting HTTP status codes for the requests. The way JSONP + jQuery work, the request works or it doesn't. If it doesn't, I specify a timeout for the request and if that timeout is reached I assume a failure (there's no way to know otherwise). I'd really like to be able to respond to a 404 vs a 500 error from the API server.

This led me to thinking a local proxy may work better - but it would then tie up server-side resources (server that holds the jQuery application + Sinatra application) instead of client resources (the browser). That can certainly add up when each page load is 4+ requests to the API server, even though it wouldn't block the application from loading.

I understand this is not a true "question" - so feel free to flag this / close it if inappropriate. However, I'd really like to get some opinions on the subject. I'm introducing some complexity by developing a local proxy in Ruby.

Comment: I changed the tags for your question; it has nothing to do with ruby or ruby on rails.

Comment: it's late, you're right! sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

I'd stick to JSONP and the direct communication between the subdomains.

Also, you might want to check out [(hacky) methods of using iframes for communication](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/09/15/iframes-onload-and-documentdomain/). Iframes are not subject to the inter-subdomain restriction. They can communicate as long as both subdomains belong to the same top domain.

Answer (score 0):

JSONP has some limitations and is not your only option.  Since you control both domains have you considered using CORS?  If not, check it out: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

You can read about JSON-P vs. CORS here: http://json-p.org/

Comment: I would love to use CORS - but the lack of support in IE7 is unfortunately a deal breaker at the moment.

Comment: If that's the case then why not pass back a response code with your json response?  If you get no response then it's a pretty safe bet that there's a server side problem and your code would be a 500.  If that's not sufficient then a proxy would probably be better for you.  Hopefully, with IE7 usage dwindling, this will not be an issue for you much longer.